# Understanding a notation: what is $C^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Please help me decipher the abbreviations in the third row: it's describing a function $f$ that belongs to a set $C^2(\mathbb{R})$. What is $C^2(\mathbb{R})$?

[image]

Comment: It means that if $f\in C^2(\Bbb R)$ then $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and is twice differentiable and the first two derivatives are continuous. The $C$ means "continuous", and the number is the times that the derivative is continuous. The $(\Bbb R)$ is a shorthand of $(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$, that represent the domain and codomain of the derivatives and the original function.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you, Clement C.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $C^2(\mathbb R)$ is the set of all functions on $\mathbb R$ that are twice continuously differentiable.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Thank you, Janik!